# Search : features that need to be activated (or not)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, features

I want a site to be crawled for search. In site (not collection) features which of the following features should be activated?

- Search Config Data Content Types
- Search Config Data Site Columns
- Search Config List Instance Feature
- Search Config Template Feature

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these features required to be activated to perform the Search on the Site. Search will work without these.

These features used when you want to import /export the search configuration from /to another site collection.

[SharePoint 2013 Design Manager design packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862342.aspx#package)

> You would choose this option if you are designing a site and creating
>   conditional search results, or controlling the search experience. This
>   configuration contains assets like query rules, result sources, result
>   types, and any schema and ranking models. To ensure that the import of
>   the search configuration does not fail, there must not be duplicate
>   names for any elements of the search configuration. For example, if
>   you have a query rule in a site collection named SampleQueryRule, and
>   you import it into another site collection with an existing rule named
>   SampleQueryRule, importing the search configuration fails. To prevent
>   this, you can rename or delete the query rule on the source or on the
>   target. Result sources, and the schema, also have to be uniquely
>   named. If you want to include a search configuration in your design
>   package, you must activate the following features at the site level
>   under Manage Site Features

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to activate any features in your site. Just configure the contentsource in the serchservice application in your central administration to crawl that site.

[Here's some more info on that](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219808.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You do need to make sure that the Search and Offline Availability page has the Allow this Site to Appear in search results setting enabled.